# Can not get null values with full outer join

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, left-join, outer-join

I'm using SQL Server. 
I have a table **Dim_date** with all dates of May 2020

```
Datekey
---------
20200501 
20200502
20200503
20200504
20200505
20200506
20200507
....
```

And I have a table **Fact_Controls** that have the number of controls a specific **centre** have done each day.

```
Date_Ctl | Id_Centre | No_Controls
---------------------------
20200505| 01415     |1
20200505| 01415     |1
20200505| 01415     |1
20200506| 01415     |1
20200506| 01415     |1
```

I want a query that shows me the number of controls a center has done even if it is 0 or null, for example:

```
Datekey | Id_Centre | No_Controls
---------------------------
20200501| 01415     |0
20200502| 01415     |0
20200503| 01415     |0
20200504| 01415     |0
20200505| 01415     |3
20200506| 01415     |2
20200507| 01415     |0
....
```

I'm doing this but I'm don't getting what I expecting:

```
select 
     dd.DateKey,
     sum(No_Controls) as total_controls
from 
      [Fact_Controls] fc
full outer join 
     [dm].[Dim_Date] dd on  fc.Date_Ctl = dd.DateKey
where 
     fc.[Id_Centre]='01415' 
    and fc.Date_Ctl between 20200501 and 20200520
    and dd.DateKey is null
group by dd.DateKey
```

Comment: Your `WHERE` turns the `full outer join` into a `left join`. After all, `fc.[Id_Centre]='01415'` means it connot be `null`

Comment: I.e. move the WHERE clause fc conditions to the ON clause.

Comment: So I could delete the ```filter c.[Id_Centre]='01415'``` and encapsulate the query in a ```With``` then filter it by center?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Full outer join not returning all rows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16167870/full-outer-join-not-returning-all-rows)

Comment: This is a faq. Before considering posting please read your textbook and/or manual & google any error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names & site:stackoverflow.com & tags; read many answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. Reflect your research. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An outer joined row has nulls in the columns where there is no matching row. So this

```
where fc.[Id_Centre]='01415' and fc.Date_Ctl between 20200501 and 20200520
```

will remove all the outer joined fc rows.

This

```
where dd.DateKey is null
```

on the other hand will remove all not outer joined dd rows.

Moreover, why a full outer join? Shouldn't the date table contain all dates? It seems you want a mere left outer join:

```
select
  dd.datekey,
  sum(fc.no_controls) as total_controls
from dm.dim_date dd 
left join fact_controls fc on  fc.date_ctl = dd.datekey and fc.id_centre = '01415' 
where dd.datekey between '20200501' and '20200520'
group by dd.datekey
order by dd.datekey;
```

Or (aggreation before join):

```
select dd.datekey, fc.total_controls
from dm.dim_date dd 
left join
(
  select date_ctl, sum(no_controls) as total_controls
  from fact_controls
  where id_centre = '01415'
  group by date_ctl
) fc on  fc.date_ctl = dd.datekey
where dd.datekey between '20200501' and '20200520'
order by dd.datekey;
```

Or (aggregation directly per date row):

```
select dd.datekey, fc.total_controls
from dm.dim_date dd 
outer apply
(
  select sum(no_controls) as total_controls
  from fact_controls
  where id_centre = '01415'
  and by date_ctl = dd.datekey
) fc
where dd.datekey between '20200501' and '20200520'
order by dd.datekey;
```

You can use coalesce to turn nulls to zeroes in your results.

If `datekey` + `id_centre` are unique in your table `fact_controls` you don't need aggreagtion (`SUM`) at all of course.

Comment: Thank you very much, your answer was so clear and works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Please use OUTER APPLY

```
SELECT * FROM [Dim_Date] D 
OUTER APPLY 
   ( 
   SELECT * FROM [Fact_Controls] F 
   WHERE F.Date_Ctl = D.DateKey 
   ) A 
GO
```